# Tikzposter: How to change the background of a \block?

Tags: color, tikzposter

I'm trying to obtain that the blocks on one half of the poster have, say, red background, and in the other half have, say, green background.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Look up block styles on page 13 of the manual.

Answer (score 4):

The background color of the blocks is `blockbodybgcolor`, so you can simply redefine that colour as you see fit in your document, using `\colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{<colorname>}`. Similarly, the background color of the block *title* is `blocktitlebgcolor`, so you can change that as well, if you wish.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a2paper]{tikzposter}
\author{D. Ude}
\title{FooBar}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\block{A}{This has the default colour}

\colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{green!60}
\block{B}{This is green}
{ % start a group to keep the change of title background color local
\colorlet{blocktitlebgcolor}{red!60}
\block{C}{As is this, but the title has red background}
} % end that group

\colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{cyan}
\block{D}{This is cyan}
\end{document}
```