# How does one change framecolor for individual block in tikzposter?

Tags: block, tikzposter

Can one change the colour of the line surounding `block`, `framecolor`, for individual `block`s when using `tikzposter`?

If so, how? I fail to find it out.

The background colour of a `block`, `blockbodybgcolor` is simple to change individually, so it feels strange that `framecolor` should be different.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's `blocktitlebgcolor` I think, as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343115/tikzposter-how-to-change-the-background-of-a-block/376748#376748

Comment: @Torbjørn T. is correct. You will still probably want to add the `linewidth` key to the block specification because the default frame width is very narrow (e.g. add `linewidth=10pt`).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the blockstyle used, see the file `tikzposterBlockstyles.tex`. In some of the styles you'll find `color=framecolor`, in others `color=blocktitlebgcolor`. In `Envelope` it's `blocktitlebgcolor`, so you need

```
\colorlet{blocktitlebgcolor}{<colour spec>}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what's happening is that the default line width of the frame is too narrow to see the color change.

Define a `blockstyle` with `\blockstyle{blockstylename}`. I used `\blockstyle{myblockstyle}`. To this `blockstyle`, add to the `\draw` commands `line width = x pt` where `x pt` is the desired line width of the block frame. I added `line width=10pt`. Set the style of the blocks that follow with `\useblockstyle{myblockstyle}`. Then, declare the desired `framecolor`, say magenta, with `\colorlet{framecolor}{magenta}` immediately before giving the block specifications with `\block`.

I borrowed the code from @Torbjørn T.'s answer to your last question, [Different block heights in tikzposter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443206/), to make an MWE. It gives this result, creating one block with a magenta frame and another with a cyan frame.

[image]

This is the code:

```
%From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443206/
\documentclass[
  usenames,
  dvipsnames,
  a2paper,
  subcolspace = 3 mm,
  colspace = 3 mm,
  landscape,
  innermargin = 3 mm,
  margin = 7 mm,
%  blockhorizontalspace = 5 mm, % this is not a valid option, doesn't do anything
  blockverticalspace = 5 mm,
  25 pt]{tikzposter}


\usetheme{Envelope} % See Section 5 (Rätt okej!)
\usecolorstyle[colorPalette=BrownBlueOrange]{Germany}

\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
    \setlength{\TP@blocktop}{.495\textheight}
\makeatother

\settitle{ }
\colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{MidnightBlue!100}
\colorlet{blockbodyfgcolor}{white} % color of text, no need for \color{white} everywhere


\defineblockstyle{myblockstyle}{
titlewidthscale=0.9, bodywidthscale=1,titleleft,
titleoffsetx=0pt, titleoffsety=0pt, bodyoffsetx=0mm, bodyoffsety=15mm,
bodyverticalshift=10mm, roundedcorners=5,
titleinnersep=6mm, bodyinnersep=1cm
}{
\draw[color=framecolor, fill=blockbodybgcolor, line width=10pt,  %<- added line width=10pt
rounded corners=\blockroundedcorners] (blockbody.south west)
rectangle (blockbody.north east);
\ifBlockHasTitle
\draw[color=framecolor, fill=blocktitlebgcolor, line width=10pt,  %<- added line width=10pt
rounded corners=\blockroundedcorners] (blocktitle.south west)
rectangle (blocktitle.north east);
\fi
}

\useblockstyle{myblockstyle}
\begin{columns}
    \column{0.5}
    \colorlet{framecolor}{magenta}                                %<- declare the frame color
    \block[bodyoffsetx = 0 mm,
           bodyoffsety=-2cm,
           bodyverticalshift = 0 mm,
           bodyinnersep = 3 mm,
           linewidth=10pt,        %<- need this for spacing between test2a and test2b blocks 
           titleinnersep = 0em,
           roundedcorners=0]{}{\raggedright\fontsize{60pt}{60pt}\selectfont Test1a}

    \column{0.5}
    \colorlet{framecolor}{cyan}                                    %<- declare the frame color
    \block[bodyoffsetx = 0 mm,
           bodyoffsety=-2cm,
           bodyverticalshift = 0 mm,
           bodyinnersep = 3 mm,
           titleinnersep = 0em,
           roundedcorners=0]{}{\raggedright \fontsize{60pt}{60pt}\selectfont Test1b}
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```