# Notes in Tikzposter

Tags: color, tikz-styles, notes, tikzposter

Does anyone know how to change body and frame color of just one (among a few) note in tikzposter document? Also, I'm having trouble with justifying text in notes.

Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Can you please post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Your description of what you want is not very clear. By giving some example code it is more likely that some one will be able to help you.

Comment: Please note also that not everyone is excited about this class. This is because you cannot use Ti*k*Z inside in a straightforward way without nesting `tikzpicture` environments, which is dangerous. That is to say that if you use it, better avoid using `tikzpicture`s inside. And it seems that your question may be related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/443253/121799.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys. Actually, the block question was of no help. I managed to get one note in different background color from the other notes in my poster, by realizing that as long as you are working in one column, all notes will be of the same style (e.g. default), but one can switch note's e.g. background color by working in some other column, and after leaving that column, the default style is restored. Also, I found it to be convenient, as in that way I never exceeded column length.

However, I think that this class needs lots of upgrades. I strugled throughout, finished the poster, but still not satisfied by the overall look. Also, more discussion on various problems/experiences with this class would be helpfull.

Here is a part of my code:

```
\column{0.5}
\block{Title}{Some text or figures}
\colorlet{noteframecolor}{white} % changing note's frame color NOT WORKING!!!
\colorlet{notebgcolor}{white} % changing notes background color WORKS!
\note[targetoffsety=-26.2cm,targetoffsetx=-0.6\textwidth, width=0.08\textwidth]{Notetext} % adjusting desired note position, which can be anywhere in poster, not only in corresponding column
\end{columns}
\begin{columns}.....
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an error in the documentation the command that works for me is:

```
\colorlet{notefrcolor}{white}
```

I realise this is a super late reply but hopefully it helps in the future.